# Struggling to get an image appearing behind other elements of my Tkinter based program

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

Brand new to programming, this being my first real project written in any language.

I'm currently writing the interface for a program, and im wanting to display an image behind, buttons, text boxes and other elements that will appear now and in the future over the top.

I can't work out how to shift the image to the back layer, not sure if this is how you'd phrase such a question.

Here is what it currently appears as, as you can see the image overlaps everything.

How it looks at the moment

[image: How it looks at the moment]

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFont, ImageDraw

import tkinter as tk
import subprocess


#wifi scanning into file command
savename = "net.txt"


def wifi():
        f= open(savename,"w+")
        subprocess.run("wifi scan>"+ savename, shell=True, check=True)

def statustext(): #text that appears when save button is pressed
    savestatus = Label(root, text="Scanning and saving complete")
    savestatus.grid(row=6, column=3)


def hacktext():
        hackstatus= Label(root, text="Not Done Yet")
        hackstatus.grid(row=12, column=3)

def readfile():
        f= open(savename,"r")
        subprocess.run("leafpad " +savename, shell=True, check=True)

def readtext():
        openstatus= Label(root, text="Opening in Leafpad...")
        openstatus.grid(row=15, column=3)


def hackbut():
        hackspac = Label(root)
        hackspac.grid(row=12)
        hackbutton = Button(text="Hack Password", command=lambda:[(),hacktext()])
        hackbutton.bind("<Button-1>")
        hackbutton.grid(row=14,column=3)

def textbut():
        textspac =Label(root)
        textspac.grid(row=15)
        textbutton = Button(text="Display Text File", command=lambda:[(),readtext(),readfile()])
        textbutton.grid(row=16,column=3)

root = Tk()



scanbutton = Button(text="Scan & Save", command=lambda:[wifi(),statustext(),hackbut(),textbut()])
scanbutton.bind("<Button-1>")
scanbutton.grid(row=11,column=3)
root.geometry ('320x240')

bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
background_label = Label(root, image=bg)
background_label.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the image first, _before_ the other buttons? The z-order defaults to the order that widgets are created, so widgets created later will be higher than widgets created earlier.

Comment: Just tried and sadly not Bryan, creating the image earlier doesn't seem to make any difference at all, thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Just seen a comment in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637795/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-transparent about transparency, or rather no transparency below the top-level window. hth

Comment: Try changing `background_label.grid(...)` to  `background_label.place(x=0, y=0)` and create the `background_label` first (i.e. before the `scanbutton`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much acw1668, that's exactly what i needed!