# How to make a tkinter canvas rectangle transparent?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, transparency

I need to make my tkinter rectangles transparent. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have tried to specify `alpha=".5", opacity=".5"`, and I have tried to add two more digits in the end of the color code: `fill="#ff000066"`. None of these things seem to work, I can't find the right syntax.

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill="#ff0000", alpha=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

This code gives me this message: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-alpha"`, so this is obviously not the right way to do it.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but IIRC tkinter supports four color formats: `#rgb`, `#rgba`, `#rrggbb`, and `#rrggbbaa`. What happens when you try `fill="#ff000080"`? (I'm pretty sure this is valid for HTML/CSS, not sure for tk).

Comment: It doesn't seem like it supports #rrggbbaa. Trying what you said gives me this error: _tkinter.TclError: invalid color name "#ff000080"

Comment: It's not a syntax issue. `tkinter` doesn't support the transparency of items on a `Canvas`. There are ways to make an entire top-level window transparent, but there's nothing to control it for individual widgets below that level (including `Canvas` objects).

Comment: Try adding `stipple='gray50'`, but it is not true transparency.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use transparent image to simulate the result.  Use `Pillow` to create transparent image and then use `canvas.create_image(...)` to draw it.  Below is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

images = []  # to hold the newly created image

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    if 'alpha' in kwargs:
        alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
        fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
        fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=200)
canvas.pack()

create_rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100, fill='blue')
create_rectangle(50, 50, 250, 150, fill='green', alpha=.5)
create_rectangle(80, 80, 150, 120, fill='#800000', alpha=.8)

root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: You need to install the `Pillow` module.

Comment: @acw1668 no matter what I try in my application image is always white. Did you face smt like this before?

Comment: @Alper91 Did you save a reference of the instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`?

Comment: @acw1668 yeap, it turns out the problem is with 'Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)' Iencode colors in Hex: #0101FF -> it should decode it as 1,1,255 but it devils: 257, 65332, 21122. I decoded myself: (int(color[1:3],16),int(color[3:5],16),int(color[5:7],16),55) now it works. Thanks though.

Comment: @Alper91 can you explain how to decode this, I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: `winfo_rgb()` returns color component values in the range of 0-65535, but RGB color components s in Pillow are 8-bit with a range of 0-255. So this code is passing fill colors of `(0, 32896, 0, 127)` and `(32896, 0, 0, 204)`. It seems to work, so is pillow doing an (undocumented) `% 256` on the values it receives?

Comment: `winfo_rgb("#abcdef") => (0xabab, 0xcdcd, 0xefef)` so we're lucky that the color information is in both the high and low bytes. if that weren't the case, even any reduction to 8 bit done by PIL would have caused useless values.

Comment: is there a way to do with lines

Answer (score 11):

In a canvas if you want some widget to be transparent, simply let the fill parameter be empty:

```
fill=""
```