# When making a new Pillow image in Tk.Canvas, why does an array work but not a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a translucent (RGBA) rectangle in Tkinter. I used the code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645103/12457082) to make it, but I'm having trouble understanding what the array does here. They initially wanted to make multiple rectangles, so I understand why they would use it in that respect, but when I try to change the array to a variable that, in my understanding, would do the same, it stops showing the rectangle color.

Here is the (slightly modified) code with an array for the output:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
images = []  # to hold the newly created image

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):  # x & y's dimensions
    alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
    fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
    fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)  # Returns a tuple of the color
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
    images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
    canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

create_rectangle(50, 50, 250, 150, fill='green', alpha=.5)

root.mainloop()
```

With its output:

[image]

And the same code with a variable instead of `images[-1]` after `image=`:

```
def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):  # x & y's dimensions
    alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
    fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
    fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)  # Returns a tuple of the color
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
    test_var = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=test_var, anchor='nw')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)
```

Which outputs:

[image]

If I print the `type()` of both, I get the same result (`<class 'PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage'>`), and defining the same variable and appending it (`images.append(test_var)`) gives me the correct result. It's only when the variable is used in `canvas.create_image` that the bug appears.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in `PhotoImage` - `Garbage Collector` removes `PhotoImage` from memory when it is assigned to local variable and then you see empty image.

You have to assign it to `global` variable

```
def create_rectangle(...):
    global test_var

    # ... code ...

    test_var = ...

    # ... code ...
```

or you can assign it to other object.
It is popular to assing it to some widget which will display it (`Canvas`, `Label`, `Button`).

```
def create_rectangle(...):

    # ... code ...

    test_var = ...
    canvas.test_var = test_var

    # ... code ...
```

See `Note` in documentation for [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

---

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- classes ---

# ... empty ...

# --- functions ---

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):  # x & y's dimensions
    #global photo
    
    alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
    fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
    fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)  # Returns a tuple of the color
    
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    #images.append(photo)
    canvas.photo = photo
    
    canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=photo, anchor='nw')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)

# --- main ---

#images = []  # to hold the newly created image

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

create_rectangle(50, 50, 250, 150, fill='green', alpha=.5)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pe-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

As @acw1668 mentioned in comment: if you will run `create_rectangle` many times then it will assign new image to `global` variable or `canvas.photo` and `Garbage Collector` will remove previous image from memory and image will disappear. So if you need to display all images then keep them all on list.

Comment: If you call `create_rectangle()` more than once, the previous image will still be garbage collected.  That is why list is used to store the image references in the linked solution.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, I was thinking about this. I added your suggestion to answer.