# Tkinter - uneven frames overlapping

Tags: python, tkinter, overlap, frames

Could someone please confirm if there is any possibility to create Tkinter frames with uneven dimensions overlapping, and then by using Tkinter raise function, I would like to display whichever frames is required to me, but for some reason, I couldn't find an option to do this, any suggestions/advises are much appreciated.

Something like the below in the image, yellow, green & red like to be 3 different frames

Thank you in advance..!!

[image]

Comment: Why do you want frames to overlap like that? I can't think of any cases where that would be useful. Also have you looked at the `.place` geometry manager?

Comment: You can't have transparent `Frame`s like that but you should be able to `lift()` or `lower` them as needed to get the effect. The `Frame`s must all be siblings.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I've seen UI's that have floating "palettes" like this; typically showing information or containing a list of tools or options — so it definitely can be useful in some instances. There's also something called [MDI (Multiple-document interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-document_interface).

Comment: @martineau In that case, I am very likely to use another window (with `overrideredirect`). I wouldn't use a floating frame in the main window.

Comment: @TheLizzard: That would work of course, but isn't the same thing.  MDI has been around a *long* time and been used by [many applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-document_interface#Application_examples) — so at least some folks think there are cases where it's useful. That's the point I'm making to counter yours.

Comment: do you expect all of these frames to exist in a single window, or do you want each frame to be a floating window?

Comment: My requirement is to sit all 3 frames on a single window, I remember sometime back @Bryan Oakley mentioned it's possible in one of the old posts, my apologies if I misunderstood that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, though not with transparency in the frames. If you don't really need frames and just need rectangles, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645103/7432) shows how to get transparency with images on a canvas.

Your post is unclear as to exactly what you expect, but here's an example that uses `place` to arrange the frames like in your picture. If you run the code, you can click on a frame to raise it to the top.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")

yellow_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=300, background="yellow", bd=8, relief="solid")
green_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=300, background="green", bd=8, relief="solid")
red_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=800, background="red", bd=8, relief="solid")

yellow_frame.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw")
green_frame.place(x=0, y=300, anchor="nw")
red_frame.place(x=500, y=0, anchor="nw")

for frame in (yellow_frame, green_frame, red_frame):
    frame.bind("<1>", lambda event: event.widget.lift())

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot, red on top]

[image: screenshot, green on top]

Comment: @user3101632: see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)