# canvas.delete() only working as expected once for deleting rectangle

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have this piece of code that I took from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637795/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-transparent/54645103#54645103) by @acw1668 which can create and place transparent rectangles onto a canvas.

However, I needed to be able to delete them so that they can be moved and replaced.  Initially, I thought `canvas.delete(tag)` was the way to go and added tags to the relevant lines in the function, but it does not behave as expected.

I also tried assigning the object to a variable and using `canvas.delete(variable)` but that would have been hard to execute as the rectangle was created in a function, that is called by a function, that cannot take arguments.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

images = []  # to hold the newly created image

def remove(tag):
    canvas.delete(tag):

def create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, tag, **kwargs):
    if 'alpha' in kwargs:
        alpha = int(kwargs.pop('alpha') * 255)
        fill = kwargs.pop('fill')
        fill = root.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (x2-x1, y2-y1), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=images[-1], anchor='nw', tags=tag)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, tags=tag, **kwargs)

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=200)
canvas.pack()

create_rectangle(80, 80, 150, 120, "1", fill='#800000', alpha=.8)
time.sleep(1) # Ik not to use in tkinter like this but just used to try and show what my actual program is like
remove("1")

root.mainloop()
```

But basically when I press a button that calls `remove()` the outline is not removed ever, and the fill (coloured part) is removed the first time remove is called, but when a new rectangle is created the remove button then does nothing.  I'm not sure why it would work once but not again but I would love this to work as then I can alter this function to work for my program.

Comment: You can't use tags that are simply the string representation of numeric values like `"42"`, try prefixing it with an `"_"` character — `"_42"`.

Comment: Also note that you change and move `Canvas` objects around without deleting them first — in fact is preferable not to.

Comment: @martineau In the past I have deleted then replaced an object into a new position, is this not the way to do it?

Comment: @martineau Your answer in the comments fixed the problem, thank you very much

Comment: That's good to hear—you're welcome. You can move an existing `Canvas` object using the `Canvas.move()` method, as well as the `Canvas.coords()` method. See [Methods on `Canvas` widgets](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html).