# How to change the opacity of a line?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I did some research about opacity but I didn't find anything about the lines.
I found some topics about the window or a rectangle only.

I would like to know if it is possible to have on Tkinter colored lines with a certain opacity that can be adjusted.

```
dashboard.create_line(init_x,init_y,event.x,event.y,width=pen_width,fill=pen_color,capstyle=ROUND,smooth=True,tag="line "+str(selectLine)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a tkinter canvas rectangle transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637795/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-transparent)

Comment: No because as I said in the question I had already found this for the rectangle and the window except that it does not apply to the line

Answer (score 0):

tkinter doesn't support transparent lines is the shortest answer.

### Alternate solution

If your canvas background color is static, you can use this trick.

This is a pure red `#FF0000` line with `0.5` alpha on a pure white `#FFFFFF` canvas in an external **image editing tool**.
*I used a higher line width so that it will be more visible.*
[image]

You can now use a color picker to copy this color (make sure it's `RRGGBB`)
[image]

Now you can use this color as a fill for the line in your tkinter canvas. Using a polygon for better visiblity:

```py
cv.create_polygon(10, 10, 500, 10, 500, 50, 10, 50, fill="#ff7f7f")
```

The result will look as following:

[image]

#### Notes

- This answer assumes the canvas background to be static.
- This is not really an efficient solution for this question.

Comment: It's a pity because it is supported with the rectangle or for the window though.
Personally I create a paint app and I would have liked to be able to modify the opacity of each colored line drawn on the canvas.

Comment: Transparent rectangles are also not possible. The one question linked above shows adding an image of rectangle which is transparent. If you are aiming for a paint app, use some other framework, tkinter may not be the best option suited to that.

Comment: What do you recommend?
I'm making a game that will be played online where one of the players draws and the others have to guess.
Which frameworks would be suitable for me in this case?